# Iframe works local but not on the server

Tags: html, laravel, iframe

Using an iframe I want to load a 360* (panorama, VR) viewer into my blade template.

The viewer files are in a folder inside my /public folder, so I am calling the files using the asset function:

```
<iframe src="{{asset('iframe/tour/tour.html')}}" width="100%" height="454px" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

This works properly on my local (homestead, vagrant) environment. Although when I deploy the code to my live environment it will give return errors that the files not exists.
But when I search through the server using SSH/FileZilla the files are actually in the (correct) folder.

Can the Digital Ocean server cause this problem, or is it something else?

Comment: Check the HTML source of the final page served to the browser and see what URL has been generated by Laravel/Blade for the `src` attribute. Is the URL correct? Does it point to the tour.html file on the production server?

Comment: When I go to the file on the server (http://LINKTOTHEWEBSITE/iframe/tour/tour.html) I get a laravel view error that the view doesn't exsist and when I open it on my localhost it works.

Comment: Could you add to your original question Laravel routes listing from the production server as well as the error message about the non-existent view? From you're description this seems like the URL is not treated as a file asset but is processed by some controller instead.